# Connecting JSON database with java program (notepad + command prompt)

Tags: java, json, jdbc

So I've been searching to connect a JSON database I made to a java program, I can't seem to find anything that is for this specific case, so I tried to make due with a JDBC tutorial (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/index.htm), though I've run into a handful of problems.

What I have - 
My database
A sample program for setting up the connection (I've tried to implement json with this, here lies some of the my biggest problems)
json libs (I believe I've successfully added these to my classpath, though that's all I've managed to find out how to do)

What verions/similar am I using - 
java ( j2sdk1.4.2 ) with notepad and command prompt
json-lib-2.4-jdk13 (totals 3 jar files - downloaded from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib/files/json-lib/json-lib-2.4/ )

Here is my sample program (The unchanged sample code can be found at the tutorialspoint.com link above, under the section JDBC - Sample Program, which is located on the left side of the page.):

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DatabaseTest
{

static final String JGBC_DRIVER = "com.json.jdbc.Driver"; 
    //Tutorial had the following: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
static final String DB_URL = "";
   //Tutorial states: jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP, though I saw something that was
```

//basically saying different database types have different formats...

```
static final String USER = "test";
static final String PASS = "password";

public static void main(String[]args) 
{
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.json.jdbc.Driver");

        System.out.println("Connecting to database");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

        System.out.println("Creating statement...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        /*String sql;  This section is commented so I could javac 
        *(clearing out whatever errors I could
        * tutorial then states the following, however I believe this 
        *is specific to a database format
        *sql = "SELECT id, first, last age FROM Employees";
        *The following line is how I think it would work with JSON...
        *
        *sql = Elements[0];
        *
        *ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        *
        *while(rs.next())
        *{
        *   String strName = rs.getString(name);
        *   System.out.println("Element name: " + strName);
        *}
        *
        rs.close();
        */
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try
        {
            if(stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
        }catch(SQLException se2){
        }
        try
        {
            if(conn != null)
                conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}
}
```

Here is part of my database (it holds information on the Periodic Table of the Elements, going through all 118 elements).

For testing purposes, I just want to get the attribute  for the first object in the Elements array (which is just "Hydrogen")

```
{
"Elements" : [
    {
    "name" : "Hydrogen",
    "Symbol" : "H",
    "atomicNumber" : "1",
    "electronegativity" : "2.2",
    "group" : "Hydrogen",
    "ionCharge1" : "1+",
    "ionCharge2" : "1-",
    "molarMass" : "1.01",
    "naturalState" : "Gas",
    "synthetic" : "false",
    "diatomic" : "true",
    "columnNumber" : "1",
    "columnCode" : "IA",
    "row" : "1",

    "nobleGasConfiguration" : [
        {
        "term:" : "No Noble Gas Configuration",
        "superScript" : "-"
        }
    ],
    "electronConfiguration" : [
        {
        "term" : "1s",
        "superScript" : "1"
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "name" : "Helium",
    "Symbol" : "He",
    "atomicNumber" : "2",
    "electronegativity" : "-",
    "group" : "NobleGas",
    "ionCharge1" : "-",
    "ionCharge2" : "-",
    "molarMass" : "4.00",
    "naturalState" : "Gas",
    "synthetic" : "false",
    "diatomic" : "false",
    "columnNumber" : "18",
    "columnCode" : "VIIIA",
    "row" : "1",

    "nobleGasConfiguration" : [
        {
        "term" : "[He]",
        "superScript" : "-"
        }
    ],      
    "electronConfiguration" : [
        {
        "term" : "1s",
        "superScript" : "2"
        }
    ]       
    },
    {
    "name" : "Lithium",
    "Symbol" : "Li",
    "atomicNumber" : "3",
    "electronegativity" : "1.0",
    "group" : "AlkaliMetal",
    "ionCharge1" : "1+",
    "ionCharge2" : "-",
    "molarMass" : "6.94",
    "naturalState" : "Solid",
    "synthetic" : "false",
    "diatomic" : "false",
    "columnNumber" : "1",
    "columnCode" : "IA",
    "row": "2",

    "nobleGasConfiguration" : [
        {
        "term" : "[He]",
        "superScript" : "-"
        },
        {           
        "term" : "2s",
        "superScript" : "1"
        }
    ],
    "electronConfiguration" : [
        {
        "term" : "1s",
        "superScript" : "2"
        },
        {
        "term" : "2s",
        "superScript" : "1"
        }
    ]       
    },
}
```

Questions - 
For the static final String DB_URL = ""; What format would I use for JSON?

I believe I still need to import the JSON stuff, but I have not been able to find out how (as stated at the top, the furthest I've gotten has been adding the 3 jars I've downloaded to my classpath). So that leads to my question, how would I import the library I've downloaded and added to my classpath?

Comment: Why are you using Java 1.4.2? It is ancient and given the security bugs fixed since the last release, a risk as well. Which JSON JDBC driver are you using (by the looks of it that `json-lib-2.4-jdk13` is not a JDBC driver). For the right JDBC url for a driver, you need to check the documentation of that driver.

Comment: I'm in highschool for a Computer Science 120 course, which has me using java 1.4.2, and this database stuff is for an extra project (a Periodic Table of the Elements program which when finished would be downloadable off of the school website) I haven't had a ton of experience programming yet, so I decided to do this program in the version that I was being taught. As for using that particular json lib, the following is on http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/index.html, (this page ultimately led me to downloading the 3 json jar files.): json-lib-x.x-jdk13 is compatible with JDK 1.3.1 and upwards.

Comment: That library is not a JDBC driver, it is a json parser. Where have you gotten the idea that it can be used as a JDBC driver? As to the use of Java 1.4.2, tell your teacher that he is at least 12 years out of date and exposing you, your fellow students and the school to security risks.

Comment: I got it from a mess of confusion I guess. XD Well now I know I need to find a JDBC JSON driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DB_URL` should be the path to your database - without the path to the database the Java application will not know where to query the database. Using the example from the tutorial again(`jdbc:mysql://localhost/STUDENTS`)

Comment: However, I'm using json, while the tutorial did not give an example with json. I would try to implement json into what tutorial gave me, however some sections later the tutorial shows a chart. The chart suggests that different databases use different URL formats. (The section that hard the chart is JDBC - Connections). For example the format for an oracle database is jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port Number:databaseName, according to the tutorial. Which has differences compared to that msql format (particularly on the right side of the format).

Comment: It is actually much easier to use the Volley library for this sort of application, it has inbuilt methods for reading JSON responses - here is a link to a tutorial that I found useful when learning Volley (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FzwBYPzCIHk) hope this helps

Comment: Sorry for the edit, I tried to go to a new line - learning that pressing enter "adds the comment"

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary for you to use JSON to parse the data anyway, if you are following the tutorial that you linked the data can be read fine without the need for JSON - just tested it..

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to look at it again. I'll be losing internet for about an hour (school's ending)